# Variables in function expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, expression, frontend

the last few days i red a lot about the difference of function expression and declarations in javascript. Most of the time it said that function expression are the preferred way to create functions in javascript. Sometimes it said the opposite, so i'm not sure, but i stay with expressions for now.

But there is one thing about expressions i couldn't find as an example. It might be a stupid question, but i would really like to know. Lets assume we have a function expression like

```
var nav = {
    init: function() {
        // Code
    }, 
    open: function() {
        // Code
    },
    close: function() {
        // Code
    }
};
```

In that case it is a function for a drop down navigation or something. You should be able to open and close it, just as an example. Now i'm asking you, how do i define variables in that code, so i can use those both in the "open", "close" and "init" functions? In that particular case i probably need variables like:

```
var
    $nav = $(".nav"),
    navHeight = $nav.height(),
    navTest = "Test";
```

How would you normally do that? It may be that this questions was already answered elsewhere, but i really couldn't find anything, maybe because i searched for the wrong keywords.

I would be really thankful if somebody could explain me / send me a link to a tutorial - for an javascript function beginner :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep shared variables in closures that keep them private to the methods of your object. A common technique is the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

You might also be interested in [Private Members in Javascript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Comment: Thanks for your link, i'm still new to javascript and will only use it for frontend related stuff (simple stuff to do some animations on scrolling for example, a slider, a gallery etc.). What i always did was just writing down all the different jQuery click, hover etc. functions after each other. So to stay with my nav example i did: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hcdHs

Comment: So i'm not sure if for my needs and experience i need private and public function (i am not even sure, when to use which of them), i just want to write code, that is more structured, that is why i came up with function expressions, which seem structured to me. Is this the right way for me, what do you think or how what you as an expert handle the code (see code pen above)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are creating functions as properties of the object `nav`. You can simply add variables as other properties along with those functions.

```
var nav = {
    myHeight: 12,
    height: function() {
        return this.myHeight;
    },
    increaseHeight: function(howMuch) {
        this.myHeight += howMuch;
    }
    init: function() {
        // use this.myVariable here
    }, 
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks that answers my question for the variables. Where do i declare variables if i need them for different expressions? So for example i need the "var $body = $("body")" in both "var nav = function() { ... }" and "var something = function() { ... }"? Do i just write it at the top of the file or is there any better way?

Comment: Well, you can just write it at the top of the file, but that will make it another global variable (like `nav`). You may consider to use the module pattern to avoid cluttering the global scope with another variable, and put `$body`, `nav` and `something` all inside the same module and exposing only the variables you want.

Comment: Thank you, i will have a look at the module pattern and see if i somehow understand it.

Comment: The key to understand the module pattern that in Javascript functions are not just methods in Java or functions in C, they can also hold data. Do you have programming experience in another language? If yes, I can try to expand my answer to explain the module pattern comparing with it.

Comment: I'm a webdesigner and doing frontend development as well. Mostly it is just HTML and CSS with some Javascript / jQuery to animate some stuff, creating sliders, galleries or stuff like that. So i'm not really doing the hard coding in Javascript, i just need to bring some structure into my code. You can check my answer to RobG in this thread to see, how my javascript code looked like until now. That is why i had a look into javascript functions to bring order in my Javascript files by creating functions. One for a slider, the other one for a navigation, whatever.

Comment: For some stuff like sliders i create a jQuery plugin most of the time, but that isn't useful for every small task in a website, that is why i need another way. I thought javascript function expression could do that and they probably can, but the module pattern looks more solid / "professional" to me, but i'm not sure if i need to get so "deep" into this javascript or if simple expression function do the job for me as well. Thanks very much for your help though, appreciate it. Would really like to vote your answear up, but i don't have enough reputation yet.